# Dynamic hostname in Smarty input field with jQuery on click event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, templates, smarty

At the moment I am trying to create an dynamic hostname with an jQuery on click event. I have this so far

**Smarty:**

```
<div>
  <input class="hostname-box" type="text" name="domain" required="" value="">
  <a href="#host" class="button">Add</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#submit" class="button">Order</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
var jHostName = $('.hostname-box');
var hostNameValue = jHostName.text().trim();

var text = "";
var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
   text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

if(hostNameValue === '') {
     jHostName.val(text+".hostname.local");
}
});
```

I can generate an text on click like random.hostname.local. But the goal is to achieve to generate an text like **vps{random}-{currentDate}.hostname.local**.

Comment: what format you want `currentDate` to be

Comment: @JohnLee d-m-y format or y-m-d  does not matter that much for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```js
    var hostNameValue = '';
    var text = "vps-";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ ) {text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));}

    let date = new Date();
    text += '-'+date.toISOString().substr(0,10);
  
    if(hostNameValue === '') {
      console.log(text+'.hostname.local');
    }
```